# Arranging Data from two different data frame based on the Datetime Column

Tags: python-3.x

I have two data frame with different values. The First Column of both the data set are same type ('Date and Time') but the frequency is different. For Example in one date set parameter are arranged in 5 minutes of interval and in another data set parameter are arranged in 15 minutes of interval. Can I transfer the average value in 15 minutes from one data set to other data set using python? Example of data shown in picture:

[image]

I have used pd.merge and pd.concat but they are not working at all

Comment: Does it have to be done in python? this can easily be done in `bash` using `join`

Answer (score 0):

you have to add an ID in both datasets to merge

Answer (score 0):

I would resample the first dataframe with 
df1.resample('15T').mean(), and then pd.concat.

For example,

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=12, freq='5T')
series1 = pd.Series(range(12), index=index)
series2 = pd.Series([0.1*x for x in range(12)],index=index)
df1 = pd.concat( [series1,series2], axis=1)
df1.columns = ["Value1","Value2"]

df1 = df1.resample('15T').mean()

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=4, freq='15T')
series1 = pd.Series(range(4), index=index)
series2 = pd.Series([0.01*x for x in range(4)],index=index)
df2 = pd.concat( [series1, series2], axis=1)
df2.columns = ["Value3", "Value4"]

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], join="inner",  axis=1)
df
```

produces

```
                   Value1   Value2  Value3  Value4
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1       0.1     0       0.00
2018-01-01 00:15:00 4       0.4     1       0.01
2018-01-01 00:30:00 7       0.7     2       0.02
2018-01-01 00:45:00 10      1.0     3       0.03
```